# Do App Scripts Transfer Ownership with Drive Files

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created many google sheets files with app scripts. My google account will be deleted soon and I have transferred ownership of the google sheets to a coworker. Will the app scripts also transfer?

Comment: Yes............

Answer (score 0):

Any script projects [bound](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) to a spreadsheet inherit access rights from their parent spreadsheet. They are owned by the account who owns the spreadsheet.

[Standalone](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone)  script projects have their own access rights, so their ownership should be transferred separately.